# File sent to email with golang

Tags: postgresql, api, file, go, email

In a job application made with Golang gin rest api, it sends the form to the e-mail recipient, the user successfully transmits the data, shows this data as "[binary data]" in the choosefile section of the database, but when the recipient opens the file, he encounters this error and the file does not open.

> ```
> Error
> Failed to load PDF document.
> ```

In debugging, this is output, but in the error, I do not save it to the file, as in the codes, a user sends the file to the recipient via the form via e-mail.

> 2023/03/13 17:28:46 open C:\fakepath\deneme.pdf: The system cannot
> find the path specified. exit status 1

```
    type forms  struct {
    ChooseFile     string `json:"choosefile"`
}



router.POST("/post", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Get form data
        var form forms
        if err := c.BindJSON(&form); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Invalid form data"})
            return
        }

        // Save to database

        if _, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO tablo( choosefile ) VALUES ($1)",  form.ChooseFile); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Database error"})
            return
        }
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM tablo")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
        file, err := os.Create("./")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        // Print results to file
        for rows.Next() {
            var id int
            var choosefile string
    
            err := rows.Scan(&id, &choosefile,)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Fprintf(file, "%d,%s\n", id,  choosefile)
        }

        // Send an email
        auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "xxx@gmail.com", "xxx", "smtp.gmail.com")

        to := []string{"xxx@gmail.com"} 
        // Read the file contents
        fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(form.ChooseFile)
        if err != nil {
            // Handle error
        }

        // Encode the file contents to Base64
        encodedContent := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(fileContent)

        // Attach the file to the email
        msg := []byte("To: " + strings.Join(to, ",") + "\r\n" +
            "Subject: JobApply Form Submission\r\n" +
            "MIME-version: 1.0;\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"boundary123\"\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            "--boundary123\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
        
            "--boundary123\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" + filepath.Base(form.ChooseFile) + "\"\r\n" +
            "\r\n" +
            encodedContent + "\r\n" +
            "--boundary123--")

        if err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587", auth, "example@gmail.com", to, []byte(msg)); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Failed to send email"})
            return
        }

        // Send successful response
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "success"})
    })
```

Comment: Where are you setting the port for the fetch?

Comment: I set it in portal 3000

Comment: I don’t understand. You want to post to 8080, not 3000.

Comment: react.js 3000 works, main.go 8080 works

Comment: Where are you setting the port for the  fetch?

Comment: that's all my codes

Comment: You need to post to port 8080.

Comment: how can I do it

Comment: By using a complete URL with the port.

Comment: This is a different question now. Check your server logs to see what the cause is.

Comment: this error appears in console
OST http://localhost:8080/send-email net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: 9090 != 8080, but if you get a connection refused then either it isn't running or it's blocked, e.g., by a firewall.

Comment: Have you got a type definition for `EmailMessage`? You didn't include that in the question.

Comment: Because there's an internal server error? You need to look at the logs/stacktrace/etc to see what the error is.